# ggplot showing names of selected ids

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a scatterplot using ggplot instead of plot and
produce this scatterplot where some IDs have different colors
and labeled:

[image]

Some asked for the dput of the data, so I added the dput in the end.
The problem with adding dput, the quesiton won't go through because
it shows too much coding compared to the question content, so that's
why I avoid it, and the head of dput is not helpful in reproducing the
real data.

I want to be able to plot all the values then show the name
for a selected IDs, not all of them.

This what I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

fig5ctrial<-read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5mintab.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)


a_select<- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")

selalpha <- fig5ctrial[match(rev(a_select), fig5ctrial$geneIDs), ]
alphanames<-fig5ctrial$geneIDs

attach(fig5ctrial)

z1 <-plot(a.donor, a_cells, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p alpha cells ", pch=19)
text(a_cells~a.donor, labels=alphanames,data=fig5ctrial, font=2)


z01 <- 
#Plot
ggplot()+
#assign alpha cell 
  geom_point(fig5ctrial,aes(a.donor, a_cells))+
#assign all cells
  geom_point(fig5ctrial,aes(all_donors, all.cells))+
#assign IDs of interest
  geom_point(fig5ctrial,aes(all_donors, all.cells, color = factor(selalpha)))+

#Add labels
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5ctrial,
                              geneIDs %in% a_select),
                  aes(label=geneIDs),show.legend = F)
```

Comment: Rather than asking us to download and import data in unknown formats (`data2` has 6 columns, but no column names - not sure how you expect us to use it) before we can start to work on the interesting part of the problem, please share a small reproducible example. Perhaps create a small sample data set - say 10 gray points and 3 blue points, and share it with `dput()` or valid R code that is copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from **@r2evans** is tremendously complete (upvoted for the very well explained details) and better than this. I used the same `ggrepel` strategy, but with a simulated variable over your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
#Data
fig5ctrial <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/alphacell.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Group
fig5ctrial$allcellstypes <- sample(1:2,nrow(fig5ctrial),replace = T)
fig5ctrial$geneIDs <- trimws(fig5ctrial$geneIDs,whitespace = '\'')
#Plot
ggplot(fig5ctrial,aes(X...donor., a.cells, color = factor(allcellstypes)))+
  geom_point()+
  #Add labels
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5ctrial,
                              geneIDs %in% a_select),
                  aes(label=geneIDs),show.legend = F)+
  labs(color='allcellstypes')
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** After playing with data from OP, here a possible sketch to solve the issue (Remember in the last attempt we merged all data):

```
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
#Data
fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.xlsx('fig5cwithoutdesc.xlsx',1,colIndex = 1:4)
ids <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")
#Clean gen id
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))
#Plot
ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,aes(a_donor, a_cell,color=(geneIDs %in% ids)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','blue'))+
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs %in% ids),
            aes(label=geneIDs),force=19)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck, I wanted to plot whole IDs too, if you check image of the plot, it has gray dots extended between the corners, these are the whole IDs, at the same time I want to show the name of IDs of interest, not all of them, in your example all the IDs showing their names, I only wanted the selected IDs

Comment: @user432797 Which are the interested ids? You can play in the geom_text() with the id variable!

Comment: these are the IDs  `a_select<- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")`  I'm sorry that I did not include them earlier, I apologize, how to do that with geom_text()? @Duck

Comment: @user432797 I have added a new code considering the vector you shared! Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you @Duck ! I'm getting this error: `Error in trimws(fig5ctrial$geneIDs, whitespace = "'"): unused argument (whitespace = "'") ` Also how to show the the rest of the gray dots?

Comment: @user432797 Please notice that it must be "'\'' also, if your variable does not have quotes you can omit that. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: From my understanding is that I need to plot three geom_point in ggplot to get the same plot in the image, I updated my question with new trial, but I did not come with the figure that I expected. It was way off @Duck

Comment: @user432797 I am not clear of what you want. Consider inviting me to chat and I would be pleased of helping you!

Comment: Thank you so much @Duck ! that would be great! I appreciate the support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225570/discussion-between-user432797-and-duck).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample that uses a little `dplyr` (not essential) and `ggrepel` (essential).

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(id = c(outer(letters, letters, paste0)), x = runif(26*26))
dat$y <- dat$x + rnorm(26*26, 0.2, 0.2)
dat[1:3,]
#   id         x         y
# 1 aa 0.9148060 0.9611270
# 2 ba 0.9370754 1.0316538
# 3 ca 0.2861395 0.4818541
```

Code for the plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

# dots we want to highlight
interesting <- c("mg", "qx", "zz")

dat %>%
  mutate(id = replace(id, !id %in% interesting, "")) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = (id %in% interesting))) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("FALSE" = "black", "TRUE" = "red")) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = id), color = "red",
    nudge_x = 0.5, direction = "x", hjust = 0)
```

[image: sample ggplot2]

Notes:

- `dplyr` can easily be removed here, replaced with `transform` and perhaps a temp-variable;
- the `id=replace(...)` portion is to remove the label (`id`) for any uninteresting variables, so that `geom_text_repel` will only label the interesting ones;
- there are other techniques for highlighting specific dots, including adding another `geom_point(..., data=~subset(., id %in% interesting))`, but that *adds* more points ... and in some graphic formats (pdf, svg) this produces extra objects and therefore might have unintended consequences. Coloring the points in this way will be more difficult if you are already using `aes(color=.)` elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans I get an error ` Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `id`.
✖ 'match' requires vector arguments
ℹ Input `id` is `replace(id, !id %in% interesting, "")`.
Traceback:

1. alphacellv %>% mutate(id = replace(id, !id %in% interesting, 
 .     "")) %>% ggplot(., aes(x, y))`

Comment: If you're using my code with your (recently-added) data, then ... did you update the variable names for what you actually have? I don't know what to make of your `allcells` data ... it is not CSV, not numeric, and not something I would associate with an `aes`thetic. Perhaps you could explain what `"-0.188 0.502 NA NA NA 0.597"` means in context of one cell value?

Comment: The gray dots in the plot supposed to be all, because if I plot only the alphacell file, then it will only show dots on the corners like in @Duck example below, but I want to plot whole IDs and show the selected IDs names only with the assigned color.

Comment: I'm sorry, I placed the files and I though I presented my question to an understandable format, I apologize @r2evans